# Agregar una nueva tabla database firts a mvc ef core

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Muy buenas noches, a todos los colaboradores, tengo una consulta que hacerles.
quiero agregar una nueva tabla a mi modelo ef core.
Como lo hago ya busque ayuda en internet pero no consigo dar con una respuesta a mi problema.
La tabla la tengo creada en sql server
tengo vs 2020
he elegido este tipo de proyecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano agradezco todo tipo de ayuda con este problema.

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que realizar code first con scaffold, te dejo un link donde utilizo una base ya creada en un proyecto .net.

https://vbpuntonet.blogspot.com/2022/02/creacion-de-crud-con-blazor-parte-1.html?m=1

Posteriormente para agregar una nueva tabla a una base de datos, debes crear un modelo (una clase) donde debes agregar todos los campos de tu nueva tabla como:
Campo1 {get;set;}
Campo2 {get;set;}
Etc
En la consola realizas:
P>migratión nombre_migracion
P>update-datase

Comment: De antemano muchas gracias, pero lo que trato de hacer es evitar hacer crear clases antes, quiero crear mis tablas en sql y luego pasarlas a mi dbcontext

Comment: Que versión de .net estás utilizando? A partir de la versión .net 5 la única forma de agregar tablas es creando clases.

Comment: .net 6, ahora le agregue a mi scafold     esto -force y sí me las agrego pero me borro todos los dataanotations que tenía hecho previamente

Comment: Después de ejecutar scaffold, ejecutas un migration y borras el contenido de los archivos que sea crean, solo dejas las declaraciones up y down, posteriormente ejecutas update-datase, con esto habrás creado la primera migration en blanco, ahora crea las nuevas clases modelo con lo campos de tus tablas y vuelve a ejecutar migration y update-datase. Cuan realizas migration después de un scaffold te toma todas las tablas como nuevas por eso te borra las data anotationd. O puedes crear la primera migration con -ignore para que no tome en cuanta las tablas de la bases de datos cradas con scaffold.